# Null pointer using const instead of variable declaration

Tags: c, arrays, variables, constants, shuffle

I have a problem I can't figure out. I wrote this code to shuffle the elements of an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

const char *array[]={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 int i, tmp, randomize, size;

 size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array);

 srand(time(NULL));

 for(i=size;i>0;i--){
  randomize=0+(rand()%size);
  tmp=(int)array[i];
  array[i]=array[randomize];
  array[randomize]=(char*)tmp;
 }

 for(i=0;i<size;i++)
  printf("%s", array[i]);   
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, this is the iutput:

```
azlngiwexbv(null)uscphqjyrodmtk
```

I can't understand why the pointer is sometimes null and I can't understand why, changing the source code in this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 char *array[]={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
 int i, tmp, randomize, size;

 size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array);

 srand(time(NULL));

 for(i=size;i>0;i--){
  randomize=0+(rand()%size);
  tmp=(int)array[i];
  array[i]=array[randomize];
  array[randomize]=(char*)tmp;
 }

 for(i=0;i<size;i++)
  printf("%s", array[i]);    
 return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine.
Thanks.

Comment: `tmp=(int)array[i];`...why?

Comment: To avoid this warning:

Comment: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   tmp=array[i];
      ^

Comment: not the cast, why the whole statement is there? it's implementation defined behaviour, don;t rely on that.

Comment: tmp should be `char *` instead of `int`.

Comment: Your title is not correct. Your main difference is making a global variable a local automatic one. The array itself is not const in any of your 2 versions.

Comment: @Gerhardh-- `array` is an array of pointers to `const char`, as declared in the first version. The pointers themselves are of course not `const`. OP has 2 problems here: the cast to `int`, which is wrong; storing a `const` value in a non-`const`-qualified type, which could lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start loop from `size-1`, you are pointing out of array in `array[size]` (first loop iteration).

```
 for (i=size-1; i>=0; i--)
```

Comment: Out of array, picking the nul termination char which explains null char output

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no, not at all. Even if `array` was nul-terminated (it's not), the null would still be within its bounds. This is simply UB.

Comment: pbn, your suggestion works, thanks. But I still not understand why, declaring the variable char *array in the main function, the program works :-\

Comment: Oh you are right. It is just that strings written that way are weird.

Comment: There is no string involved at all. It is an array of pointers, not an array of char.

Comment: @CarloDiDato your second version of code does not work for me, it results in segmentation fault

Comment: @pbn different OS and or compiler? On windows I can compile and run it
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/gcc.exe -c  "C:/test/shuffle/shuffle/main.c" -g -O0 -Wall  -o ./Debug/main.c.o -I. -I.
C:/TDM-GCC-32/bin/g++.exe -o ./Debug/shuffle @"shuffle.txt" -L.
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/test/shuffle/shuffle'
====0 errors, 0 warnings====

Comment: @pbn, I compiled both codes on Linux (Debian) using gcc, no segmentation fault but same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid casting whenever possible, and it is rarely necessary to do so.

Unless you plan on using `argc` and `argv[]`, use the simpler form for `main()`: `int main(void)`. This will remove some compiler warnings, and you should have these enabled; remove *all* warnings emitted by your compiler.

You cast a pointer to `char` to `int` to store it in `tmp`, and then you cast `tmp` back to `(char *)`. Just declare `tmp` as a pointer to `char` to start with. The first loop counts down from `size` to 0; this is out of array bounds to start, but why not just use the conventional loop construction: `for (i = 0; i < size; i++)`? Also, you should consider using `size_t` for array indices; it is an unsigned integer type guaranteed to be able to hold any array index, and is also the type returned by the `sizeof` operator.

Further, in your first version you have declared `array` as an array of pointers to `const char`s. You can do this, but you need the temporary storage variable `tmp` to agree with the `const` type qualifier.

Here is your code with the above changes. There are no casts, it compiles without warnings, and it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *array[] = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};

    const char *tmp;
    size_t i, size;
    int randomize;

    size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        randomize = (rand() % size);
        tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[randomize];
        array[randomize] = tmp;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%s", array[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```